# SharePoint 2010 List Excel Export Error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, excel, excel-services

I have some problems about exporting a SharePoint List to excel. I'm getting "Excel cannot connect to the SharePoint list" error while exporting it to excel. There wasn't any error in the same list before and there is not any error while exporting other lists to excel. There is no additional info, any logs. Any ideas about the problem?

P.S: List has more than 10000 items.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Is this in SharePoint 2010? I'm thinking it could be a throttling issue.

Comment: Yes, this is SharePoint 2010. Export action were working correctly till last week. But now it causes that error.

Comment: You could try and temporarily disable throttling on the list to see if it helps [this link](http://norpoint.wordpress.com/2012/07/12/change-or-disable-throttling-settings-for-large-sharepoint-lists/) shows how to disable it. Also worth looking at your logs around the time you try the export to see what messages you get.

Comment: Disabling the throttling didnot work for me. I searched logs and I found this exception:


_Failed to load ... with error: 'Unable to open workbook due to unexpected exception: Microsoft.Office.Excel.Server.Host.HostFileException ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException_

But there is a list and I can reach this list over web and SPD2010.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar case when a user in my company's sharepoint (10) could not export a list of a subsite. By similar, i mean that the message shown was "cannot connect to server at the moment. Your data will not be saved."

After checking the user's permissions, the error was unexplained, meaning that a user of the same permission levels could export the list without any problems.
Checking the performance on the task manager tab, the laptop was running for about 40 days, so what i did was change the security settings (IE -> Internet Options -> Security Tab) to "no security", at all and then reinstall all previous measures, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: An interesting scenario :/ Finally I've upgraded to SharePoint 2013 and problem had gone.

Comment: Yes, and not to mention, that the user could export the list if he logged in to the sharepoint from another users PC.
Really strange how SP10 handles security...