# Excel cannot connect to the SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, excel-services

I'm getting this error while exporting a custom list to excel. Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

[image]

[Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66402/sharepoint-2010-list-excel-export-error) is the same question. Still couldn't solve this error.

P.S.: "Check for server certificate revocation" setting in InternetExplorer did not solve my problem.

Comment: So, i am having the same issue ... did you figure out how to solve this..
In my case, my config is: Sharepoint 2013 with Excel 2010.
It worked once ..

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't. Still have same problem. I copied list items to another list and changed list completely.